# NVIDIA 430.09 Not taking Header file for Linux

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, nvidia, manjaro

I have GTX 1650 and I am using Manjaro 64 bit and Kernel 58, but when i try to install Driver 430.09 with this command:

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.09.run --kernel-source-path /usr/include/linux/
ERROR: The kernel header file '/usr/include/linux//include/linux/kernel.h' does
       not exist.  The most likely reason for this is that the kernel source
       path '/usr/include/linux/' is incorrect.
```

and if I use:

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.09.run --kernel-source-path /usr/

ERROR: The kernel source path '/usr/' is invalid.  Please make sure you have
       installed the kernel source files for your kernel and that they are
       properly configured; on Red Hat Linux systems, for example, be sure you
       have the 'kernel-source' or 'kernel-devel' RPM installed.  If you know
       the correct kernel source files are installed, you may specify the
       kernel source path with the '--kernel-source-path' command line option
```

How could I use `/usr/include/linux/` as kernel-source-path.
Try 1: I have also used 455.28 for installation and same problem arises.

Answer (score 1):

The `--kernel-source-path` option requires the headers for an installed kernel, not `/usr/include/linux/`.

Normally you do it this way:

`sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-430.09.run --kernel-source-path=/lib/modules/${kernel-version}/source`

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/include/linux` contains the kernel headers for the kernel's *user-space interfaces* but compiling the modules requires the headers for *all kernel interfaces*. The former is just a limited sub-set of the latter.

Usually, when the appropriate package is installed, in modern distributions, a `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build` (or `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/source`) symbolic link is added, which will point to the appropriate path. If this link exists and is valid, the NVidia driver installer will also use it automatically unless overridden on the command line.

In Manjaro, if the kernel package is named `linux[version]`, the corresponding kernel headers package (which you need to have installed in order to compile any third-party kernel modules, like Nvidia's) seems to be named `linux[version]-headers` respectively.